# Scroll images manually on markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to add images to a README.md (markdown) file, but the user can change the image by pressing a button or an arrow?

The idea is that until now I've been using GIFs but the reader can't control how much time he wants to spend looking at a slide.

Does anyone know a way to do this in markdown for github ?

Thanks for your help